# Is Tensorflow Object Detection Aspect Ratio height/width or width/height?

Tags: object, tensorflow, detection

I'm playing around with Tensorflow's Object Detection models and want to provide my own custom aspect ratios. In the config file it could look something like this:

```html
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 4
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: .5
        aspect_ratios: 2.
        aspect_ratios: 10.0
        reduce_boxes_in_lowest_layer: true
      }
```

Digging through the source code, it isn't obvious to me whether the aspect ratio is defined as height/width or width/height. I assumed that it's width/height (so 10 would have w:h of 10:1) but if I'm wrong I know my model will train very poorly!

Comment: I looked at the docs and there is no specific indication if it is w/h or h/w, they even mentiona paper and in the paper there is no specification. However the standard for aspect ratio is width/height... if you want you can post a comment on the repo to clarify that. Also, I could write an answer with some references that indicate it should be w/h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our conversion in the codebase is: **aspect_ratio = width/height**, which follows the general definition of aspect ratio: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(image).

Answer (score -1):

due to opencv   doc
aspect ratio = width / height
check [this link](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d32/tutorial_py_contour_properties.html).